# I keep getting this tensorflow error when training a linear classifier: [Labels must be >= 0. ] [Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Here is my code below and it fails when I train the data the y train column only has values -1 or 1. Does anyone have any insight here?

```py
data = pd.read_csv('../../dataset.csv')

X = data.copy()

Y = X.pop('result')

X = data.drop(columns=['result'])

df_train, df_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, Y, stratify=Y, train_size=0.80)
# print(df_train, df_valid, y_train, y_valid, sep="\n")

NUMERIC_COLUMNS = [...]

feature_columns = []
for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.int64))
# print(feature_columns)


def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    def input_function():
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))
        if shuffle:
            ds = ds.shuffle(1000)
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
        return ds

    return input_function


train_input_fn = make_input_fn(df_train, y_train)
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(df_valid, y_valid, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

linear_estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)

linear_estimator.train(train_input_fn)
result = linear_estimator.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
print(result['accuracy'])
```

I can't find anything like this anywhere else. I thought it might be n_classes but changing it did nothing. Like I said the y_train values are only -1 or 1

Comment: What about using 1 and 0 for the target?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly i'd have to change the dataset unless there is a tensorflow function or something to change it as it comes in??

Comment: `x = (x + 1) / 2`, where x is your target column (before splitting) or you can put it in a function and use as part of preprocessing when data comes in.

Comment: _i'd have to change the dataset_... Yes, 1-0 is a convention for binary data, so I would consider transforming the target as basic _data cleaning_. You're lucky if you can get a model to work without –at minimum– some data cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier), the labels are expected to be integers in the range (0, n-1), where n is the number of classes, which is why it is expecting your labels to be 0 and 1.

If you would prefer to use your labels as -1 and 1, an option would be to define your label_vocabulary as ['-1', '1'], which is the string representation of your expected classes and then tensorflow will take care of converting these to the corresponding indices.

This is from the official documentation....
[image]